# Dash by Plotly Charts Not Rendering in Browser - _dash-update-component (500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm building a small visual web application using `Dash` by `Plotly`. The code works, but when I run it locally none of the charts actually render. The axes are there, but they aren't filled with the desirable data points. I'm not sure if this is because I have my `.csv` file saved locally(?) although I've done something like this in the past and it worked fine.

When I inspect the element, I can see the `_dash-update-component` gets a `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` for each one of my callbacks.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import os 
import color_scale
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import scipy as sp
import sklearn as sk

mapbox_access_token = ''

app = dash.Dash(name=__name__)
app.config.supress_callback_exceptions = True

server = app.server
server.secret_key = os.environ.get('secret_key', 'secret')

# Color scale for heatmap (green-to-red)
color_scale = color_scale.GREEN_RED

# Load styles
css_url = 'https://codepen.io/bullybear/pen/RYbbpW.css'
css_bootstrap_url = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0- 
alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'
app.css.append_css({
"external_url": [css_bootstrap_url, css_url],
})

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/app_6/horror_films.csv')
#print(df.head())


yearmax = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)[
'Jump', 'Scary', 'Gore'].max()

yearmean = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)[
'Jump', 'Scary', 'Gore'].mean()

yearmin = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)[
'Jump', 'Scary', 'Gore'].min()

year_scores = [yearmax, yearmean, yearmin]
#print(year_scores) 


app.layout = html.Div([

# LANDING
html.Div(
    className='section',
    children=[
        html.H1('ARE YOU AFRAID OF THE DARK?', className='landing- 
text')
    ]
),
html.Div(
    className='content',
    children=[

        # SLIDER ROW
        html.Div(
            className='col',
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    id='slider',
                    children=[
                        dcc.Slider(
                            id='date-slider',
                            min=min(df['Year']),
                            max=max(df['Year']),
                            marks={
                            1974: {'label': '1974'},
                            1980: {'label': '1980'},
                            1985: {'label': '1985'},
                            1990: {'label': '1990'},
                            1995: {'label': '1995'},
                            2000: {'label': '2000'},
                            2005: {'label': '2005'},
                            2010: {'label': '2010'},
                            2017: {'label': '2017'}, 
                            },
                            value=1995,
                            ),
                            ],  
                            style={
                            'background': '#191a1a',
                            'margin-bottom': '50px'
                            }
                            )
                            ],  
                            style={
                            'background': '#191a1a',
                            })
                            ]), 

        # GRAPHS ROW
        html.Div(
            id='graphs',
            className='row',
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    className='col-4',
                    children=[
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id='graph-1',
                        ),
                    ]),
                html.Div(
                    className='col-4',
                    children=[
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id='graph-2',
                        ),
                    ]),
                html.Div(
                    className='col-4',
                    children=[
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id='graph-3',
                        ),
                    ])
            ],  style={
                    'padding-bottom': 100
            }
        ),

        # MAP ROW
        html.Div(
            className='row',
            children=[

                dcc.Graph(
                    id='graph-4',
                    animate=True,
                    style={
                      'width': '100%',
                      'height': 800,
                    }
                ),
            ]),

        # ABOUT ROW
        html.Div(
            className='row',
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    className='col',
                    children=[
                    html.P(
                    'Data Extracted From:'
                    ),
                    html.A(
                        'Scared To Watch',
                        href='https://www.scaredtowatch.com/'
                    )                    
                ]
            )], 



            style={
                'padding': 40
            } 
        )

    ])


# CHART 1

@app.callback(
Output('graph-1', 'figure'),
[Input('date-slider', 'value')]
) 


def update_graph_1(year_value): 


    data = go.Data([
        go.Scatter(
        name='Max Year',
        # events qty
        x=np.arange(1974, year_value),
        # year
        y=yearmax,
        mode='lines',
        marker={
            'symbol': 'circle',
            'size': 5,
            'color': '#eb1054'
        },
        hoverlabel={
            'bgcolor': '#FFF',
        },
    ),
        go.Scatter(
        name='Mean Year',
        # events qty
        x=np.arange(1974, year_value + 1),
        # year
        y=yearmean,
        mode='lines',
        marker={
            'symbol': 'circle',
            'size': 5,
            'color': '#C2FF0A'
        },
        hoverlabel={
            'bgcolor': '#FFF',
        },
    ),
        go.Scatter(
        name='Min Year',
        # events qty
        x=np.arange(1974, year_value + 1),
        # year
        y=yearmin, 
        mode='lines',
        marker={
            'symbol': 'circle',
            'size': 5,
            'color': '#52e5ec'
        },
        hoverlabel={
            'bgcolor': '#FFF',
        },
    ),
])

layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis={
        'autorange': True,
        'color': '#FFF',
        'title': 'Year',
    },
    yaxis={
        'autorange': True,
        'color': '#FFF',
        'title': 'Score',
    },
    margin={
        'l': 40,
        'b': 40,
        't': 10,
        'r': 0
    },
    hovermode='closest',
    paper_bgcolor='#191a1a',
    plot_bgcolor='#191a1a',
)

return go.Figure(
    data=data,  # 54b4e4
    layout=layout
)



# CHART 2

@app.callback(
Output('graph-2', 'figure'),
[Input('date-slider', 'value')]
)


def update_graph_2(year_value):
    bars = []
    bar = go.Bar(
            {'x':df['Film'], 'y': df['IMDB'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 
            'IMDB Score'},
            {'x':df['Film'], 'y': df['Rotten'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 
            'Rotten Tomatoes Score'},
            marker=dict(
            color='rgb(158,202,225)',
            line=dict(
            color='rgb(8,48,107)',
            width=1.5,
                    )
                    ),
            opacity=0.6
            )
     bars.append(bar)
     data = go.Data(bars,
               style={
                   'color': '#000'})
    layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Year',
        autorange=True,
        zeroline=True,
        gridwidth=1,
        zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        zerolinewidth=2,
    ),
    hoverlabel={
        'bgcolor': '#FFF',
        'font': {
            'color': 'black'
        },
    },
    margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0},
    hovermode='closest',
    paper_bgcolor='#191a1a',
    plot_bgcolor='#191a1a',
                    )
return go.Figure(
    data=data, 
    layout=layout
    )



@app.callback(
Output('graph-3', 'figure'),
[Input('date-slider', 'value')]
)


def update_graph_3(year_value):


    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]
    data = go.Data([
    go.Scatter(
        x=dff['Gore'],
        y=dff['Jump'],
        text=dff['Film'],
        mode='markers',
        marker={
            'symbol': 'circle',
            'size': dff['Scary'],
            'color': '#C2FF0A'
        },
        hoverlabel={
            'bgcolor': '#FFF',
            'font': {
                'color': 'black'
            },
        },
    )
],
    style={
    'color': '#FFF'})

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=True,
    xaxis={
        'color': '#FFF',
        'autorange': True,
        'title': Gore,
    },
    yaxis={
        'color': '#FFF',
        'autorange': True,
        'title': Jump,
    },
    margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0},
    hovermode='closest',
    paper_bgcolor='#191a1a',
    plot_bgcolor='#191a1a',
)

return go.Figure(
    data=data,
    layout=layout
)


@app.callback(
Output('graph-4', 'figure'),
[Input('date-slider', 'value')]
)

def update_graph_4(year_value):


    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value] 

    data = go.Data([
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=dff['lat'],
        lon=dff['lon'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.Marker(
            size=dff['Scary'],
            colorscale=color_scale,
            cmin=dff['Scary'].min(),
            color=dff['Scary'],
            cmax=dff['Scary'].max(),
            colorbar=dict(
                title='Total Scares Across The Globe'
            ),
            opacity=0.5
        ),
        text=dff['Film'],
        hoverlabel={
            'bordercolor': 'transparent',
            'font': {
                'color': '#FFF'
            }
        }
    )
],
    style={
    'height': 800
}
)

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        pitch=0,
        zoom=1.8,
        style='dark'
    ),
    paper_bgcolor='#191a1a',
    plot_bgcolor='#191a1a',
)

return go.Figure(
    data=data,
    layout=layout
)




# Run Dash Server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: could you provide the code? and before doing any action wich triggers the callback, do you have the good render?

Comment: @Alexis here is the full code